# How to perform verifyWithDelay on expected calls in OCMock <2.2.4

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, ocmock

In OCMock the verifyWithDelay function was added in 2.2.4. I am working on a large project using an earlier version but need this functionality. Is anyone aware of a workaround for delaying a verify call on an expected mock call?

Comment: Just to confirm: is it not possible to upgrade to OCMock 2.2.4? I'm asking because there shouldn't be any compatibility issues between OCMock 2.2.4. and the versions before it.

Comment: True, I updated to 2.2.4 and I haven't noticed any issues yet and I can verify expectations with a delay.